# How to setup font and size for entire workbook instead of sheet by sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want my macro to update the entire workbooks font, size and verticalaligment but all I can find are options to do it sheet by sheet. It's not too much hassle, but I was wondering whether you can't set these globally and update the entire workbook with 1 command.

```
Sub SetFormat()
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 10
        .Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could add a loop around the code you have written, and let it loop through every sheet.

Answer (score 9):

If that suits you, you can work on `Styles`. Changing the default style of the workbook is very quick, but may have side effects. Try it.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal").Font
    .Name = "Aharoni"
    .Size = 11
End With
```

Comment: what kind of side effects?

Comment: I found that text already formatted to the workbook's default font and size are updated.  The row number and column letter font is also affected.

Answer (score 3):

This code should loop through every sheet in your workbook and change the properties.

```
Sub SetFormat()
Dim ws as Worksheet
    For Each ws in Worksheets
         With ws
            .Cells.Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
            .Cells.Font.Size = 10
            .Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
         End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with the method is that the workbook default is unchanged and new worksheets added will use the default font.